# BASH Script to find files of multiple types

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, file-search

I switch a lot of people from Windows to Linux. As we all know, not all files on Windows end at their intended location (i.e.: the Downloads folder).

I'd like to run a BASH script to search for **all** types of user files (media and documents) so I won't miss any when creating the backup before making the switch.

Comment: Have you tried `updatedb` and `locate` commands?

Comment: Will searching for the respective suffixes do it? Then you can use `find`.

Comment: I know the correct `find` arguments will do the trick, but I got lost with all the options available...